# Exception name self is not defined occurred in function <class, Method>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function/method written inside a class:

```
def minimal_percentage(self, input_col=None, perc=5, conditions=None, **kwargs):
        print("name self")
        temp = ["" for i in self.df[input_col] if len(str(i)) == 0]
        print("after self")
        lendf = self.df[input_col].shape[0]
        print("2 self")
        if((len(temp)/lendf) < lendf*perc/100):
            conditions = conditions.replace("df","self.df")
            print(conditions)
            print(type(conditions))
            eval(conditions)
```

This function gets called internally by parsing the json and knowing the function name from it and calls.

```
 {
        "sheet_minimal_percentage":{
            "kwargs":{
                "input_col": "date of birth",
                "perc":5,
                "conditions": "df[input_col].map(lambda x: f'09/09/{np.array([pd.to_datetime(i).year for i in df[input_col][~df[input_col].isna()]]).sum()// (df[input_col].count())}' if (str(x) == 'nan' or str(x) == '') else pd.to_datetime(x))"
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the following:

```
output saying self is not defined occured in function class method
```

But the **print** statements **after self** and **2 self** got executed without any error. When it came to the eval only, it is showing the error. Could you help me to resolve the error?

```
STEP minimal_percentage

name self
after self
2 self
self.df[input_col].map(lambda x: f'09/09/{np.array([pd.to_datetime(i).year for i in self.df[input_col][~self.df[input_col].isna()]]).sum()// (self.df[input_col].count())}' if (str(x) == 'nan' or str(x) == '') else pd.to_datetime(x))
<class 'str'>
Exception name 'self' is not defined occured in function <class 'method'>
```

When I loaded the dataframe from excel and checked the condition, it is executing correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
ddf= pd.read_excel("C:/Users/ShreeHarsha/Documents/test2.xlsx")

t = "ddf[input_col].map(lambda x: f'09/09/{np.array([pd.to_datetime(i).year for i in ddf[input_col][~ddf[input_col].isna()]]).sum()// (ddf[input_col].count())}' if (str(x) == 'nan' or str(x) == '') else pd.to_datetime(x))"

input_col = "DATE OF BIRTH"

import numpy as np

eval(st)
```

Got the output where empty string has to be replaced by `09/09/avg` year of columns ,and here is output:

```
0     1983-06-11 00:00:00
1     1986-02-23 00:00:00
2     1998-03-25 00:00:00
3     1977-04-23 00:00:00
4     1981-04-28 00:00:00
5     1953-04-02 00:00:00
6     1992-01-23 00:00:00
7     1974-10-03 00:00:00
8     1961-06-30 00:00:00
9     1973-07-06 00:00:00
10    1977-10-25 00:00:00
11    2001-02-26 00:00:00
12    1997-01-17 00:00:00
13    1982-08-31 00:00:00
14    1973-11-13 00:00:00
15             09/09/1980
Name: DATE OF BIRTH, dtype: object
```

**PS**: In the orginal project, all **column headers** capitals are mapped to lowers, so **DATE OF BIRTH** is **equal** to **date of birth**.

this is a **another function** where it has been executed successfully

```
 def apply_multiple_conditions(
        self, conditions, values, default, output_col_name, **kwargs
    ):

        # print(conditions.replace("column", "self.df"), values)
        self.df[output_col_name] = ""
        conditions = eval(conditions.replace("column", "self.df"))
        default = default.replace("column", "self.df")
        values = eval(values)
        self.df[output_col_name] = np.select(conditions, values, eval(default))
        # print(self.df[output_col_name])
        return self.df
```

and its **json**

```
 {
        "sheet_apply_multiple_conditions": {
            "kwargs": {
                "conditions": "[(column['home zip'].str.len() != 0) & (column['home zip'].str.len() > 30)]",
                "values": "['Home zip code is greater than 5 digits.  Please shorten to 5 zip codes.']",
                "default": "str()",
                "output_col_name": "homezip_len_validation"
            }
        }
    }
```

and **output** of function where the code is excecuted successfully

```
STEP apply_multiple_conditions


After transformations
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [relationship, first name, last name, date of birth, age, gender (m or f), home zip, work zip, dental coverage status (ee, es, ec1, ec2, ef, we, ne), vision coverage status (ee, es, ec1, ec2, ef, we, ne), salary, salary mode, job title plumber, job title, occupation specialty, retiree (y or n), smoker (y or n), date of hire, std enrollment status, ltd enrollment status, basic life volume, supp life ee volume, supp life sp volume, supp life ch volume, vol life ee volume, vol life sp volume, vol life ch volume, basic ad&d volume, supp ad&d ee volume, supp ad&d sp volume, supp ad&d ch volume, vol ad&d tier, vol ad&d sp volume, vol ad&d ch volume, ltd voluntary volume, std voluntary volume, critical illness (ee, es, ec1, ec2, ef, we, ne), hospital plus insurance (ee, es, ec1, ec2, ef, we, ne), state, dental class number, vision class number, basic life class number, supp life class number, vol life class number, std class number, ltd class number, class number all products, occupation, vol ad&d ee volume, deductible insurance (ee, es, ec1, ec2, ef, we, ne), dental_coverage_present, dental_coverage_validation, vision_coverage_present, vision_coverage_validation, retiree_validation, smoker_validation, smoker_ci_validation, salarymode_validation, basiclifevol__neg_validation, basiclifevol__count_validation, supplifeeevol__neg_validation, supplifeeevol__count_validation, supplifespvol__neg_validation, supplifespvol__count_validation, supplifechvol__neg_validation, supplifechvol__count_validation, vollifeeevol__neg_validation, vollifeeevol__count_validation, vollifespvol__neg_validation, vollifespvol__count_validation, vollifechvol__neg_validation, vollifechvol__count_validation, basicad&dvol__neg_validation, basicad&dvol__count_validation, suppad&deevol__neg_validation, suppad&deevol__count_validation, suppad&dspvol__neg_validation, suppad&dspvol__count_validation, suppad&dchvol__neg_validation, suppad&dchvol__count_validation, volad&deevol__neg_validation, volad&deevol__count_validation, volad&dspvol__neg_validation, volad&dspvol__count_validation, volad&dchvol__neg_validation, volad&dchvol__count_validation, volltdvol__neg_validation, volltdvol__count_validation, volstdvol__neg_validation, volstdvol__count_validation, age_validation, gender_validation, homezip_int_validation, homezip_len_validation, workzip_int_validation, workzip_len_validation, occupation_character_validation, occupation_length_validation, job_title_character_validation, job_title_length_validation, ...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 119 columns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because of the way `eval` works, essentially, since you are implicitly passing a different object for `locals` and `globals` (since it just gets `globals()` and `locals()`), the expression is being evaluated as if it were in a class definition, which does not create an enclosing scope. The behavior is described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

> If the locals dictionary is omitted it defaults to the globals
> dictionary. If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is
> executed with the globals and locals in the environment where `eval()`
> is called.

and if to keep reading in the `exec` docs:

> Remember that at the module level, globals and locals are the same
> dictionary. If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals,
> the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class
> definition.

And class scopes *don't create enclosing scopes*, which is why you can't call methods without using `self`.

Here is another way to reproduce:

```
def foo():
    data = 42
    source  = "def bar(): return data"
    glbs = globals()
    lcls = locals()
    exec(source, glbs, lcls)
    lcls['bar']()
```

And running in a REPL:

```
In [2]: foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c19b6d9633cf> in <module>
----> 1 foo()

<ipython-input-1-63703f634871> in foo()
      5     lcls = locals()
      6     exec(source, glbs, lcls)
----> 7     lcls['bar']()
      8
      9

<string> in bar()
```

You could pass the same object to both parameters, and then it will act as if it were executed in the global context, where enclosing scopes are available:

```
In [8]: def foo():
   ...:     data = 42
   ...:     source  = "def bar(): return data"
   ...:     glbs = locals()
   ...:     lcls = glbs
   ...:     exec(source, glbs, lcls)
   ...:     return lcls['bar']()
   ...:
   ...:

In [9]: foo()
Out[9]: 42
```

But this is fundamentally a bad approach.

You should *almost certainly* just not use `eval` here. `eval` is almost never the right approach.

Comment: but self.df is a local in the environment , its not in a nested scope, the object creation assigns the value to self.df ,it should use local i.e self .df , since both locals and globals dictionaries are explicitly omitted

Comment: @SriHarsha no, `self` is local to `minimal_percentage`, but inside the lambda in your expression it is a free variable. This is *exactly* analogous to the example I gave above, where `data` is local to `foo` but a free variable to `bar`

Comment: there is another function which is similar to this , `def amc(self, conditions,values):`   `conditions = eval(conditions.replace("column", "self.df"))`   which has been executed successfully, here also if it goes with the same anaology, then this shouldnt have been executed

Comment: @SriHarsha you are going to have to provide a [mcve]. In **any case** what you have is *not expected to work* because of the facts mentioned in my answer

Comment: @juanapa.arrivillaga look at my post once again , i have an other function where eval has executed successfully, and i gave the output also, your anology is not being held there

Comment: @SriHarsha that **is not a [mcve]**

Comment: @SriHarsha but in any case, `[(column['home zip'].str.len() != 0) & (column['home zip'].str.len() > 30)]` **does not contain any nested scopes** so it **is not analogous**. I think you fundamentally do not understand what a nested scope is. The lambda expression creates a function, which creates a nested scope. On the other hand, the expression `[(column['home zip'].str.len() != 0) & (column['home zip'].str.len() > 30)]` creates no nested scopes. Please read carefully to understand my answer

Comment: i got it thank you , your explanation is correct

Answer (score 0):

As said by the @juanpa.arrivillaga, those were free variables, thats why i have passed the external dictionary to indicate the gloabls and assosciate it to locals

```
symbols = {"self": self,"input_col":input_col,"pd":pd,"np":np}
            eval(conditions,symbols)
```

or you can use

```
gbls = globals()
lcls = locals()
eval(conditions,lcls,gbls)
```

this should work